# How to insert multiple images in a table?

Tags: laravel-5

How to insert multiple images into the table?

```
Controller

    public function save(Request $request)
   {
    $images = new Image;
    $input = $request->file("image");
    if($files=$request->file('image')){
    foreach($files as $file){
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move(public_path("/images/"),$name);
        $images[]=$name;
        $images->Image         =  $input->getClientOriginalName();
    }
}
  $images->save();
  $image = Image::find($request->id);
  return Redirect::to("image")->withSuccess('Great! Image has been successfully uploaded.');
}
```

I expect to insert images into database, the the error is No message

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#mass-assignment) to insert your image name into the database. The code will be like this :

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $images = new Image;

    if ($files = $request->file('image')) {
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $name = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->move(public_path("/images/"),$name);
            $images->create(['Image' => $file]);
        }
    }

    return Redirect::to("image")->withSuccess('Great! Image has been successfully uploaded.');
}
```

You must insert it in every loop, if you use the model attribute it will just change every time the loop sets the image name.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function create(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'gallery_album_id'=>  'required',
         'image' => 'required',
         'image.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048'

    );

$input=$request->all();
$image=array();
if($files=$request->file('image')){
    foreach($files as $file){
        $name=$file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->move('images',$name);
        $image=$name;

         gallery::insert( [
    'image'=>  $image,
    'gallery_album_id' =>$input['gallery_album_name']
]);
    }

    }
   return redirect()->route('gallery')->withStatus(__('Album successfully added.'));
}
```

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks